# How to call other master components' /metrics API in a managed environment?

Tags: kubernetes, observability

I have a managed version of the Kubernetes cluster, that is, kube-apiserver / kcm / kube-scheduler / etcd is managed, and only kube-apiserver can be directly accessed through the network, and other master components cannot be accessed. Is there a way to use kube-apiserver as a proxy to access /metrics API of other master components?

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-api-machinery/1281-network-proxy#proposal), is it resolve you issue?.